# Помогите найти ошибку в JS коде. Решил написать слайдер, но почему-то не работают кнопки которые должны двигать текст и картинки

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
const upBtn = document.querySelector('.up-button')
const downBtn = document.querySelector('.down-button')

const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar')
const mainSlide = document.querySelector('.main-slide')
const slidesCount = mainSlide.querySelectorAll('div').length

const container = document.querySelector('.container')

let activeSlideIndex = 0

sidebar.style.top = `-${(slidesCount - 1) * 100}vh`

upBtn.addEventListener('click',() => {  
    changeSlide('up')
} )

downBtn.addEventListener('click',() => {
    changeSlide('down')
} )

function changeSlide(direction) {
    if(direction === 'up') {
        activeSlideIndex++
        if(activeSlideIndex === slidesCount)
        {
            activeSlideIndex = 0
        }
    } else if (direction === 'down') {
        activeSlideIndex--
        if (activeSlideIndex < 0) {
            activeSlideIndex = slidesCount - 1 
        }
    }

    const height = container.clientHeight

    mainSlide.style.transform = `translateY (-${activeSlideIndex * height}px)`

    sidebar.style.transform = `translateY (${activeSlideIndex * height}px)`
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Слайдер | Проект 3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div style="background: linear-gradient(229.99deg, #11DEE9 -26%, #017E8B 145%);">
          <h1>Snow in the desert</h1>
          <p>Love, death & robots</p>
        </div>
        <div style="background: linear-gradient(215.32deg, #F90306 -1%, #9E0706 124%);">
          <h1>Life Hutch</h1>
          <p>Love, death & robots</p>
        </div>
        <div style="background: linear-gradient(221.87deg, #8308EA 1%, #5305AF 128%);">
          <h1>Zima Blue</h1>
          <p>Love, death & robots</p>
        </div>
        <div style="background: linear-gradient(220.16deg, #FFE101 -8%, #F39102 138%);">
          <h1>Automated Customer Service</h1>
          <p>Love, death & robots</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-slide">
        <div
          style="
            background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601574968106-b312ac309953?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1996&q=80');
          "
        ></div>
        <div
          style="
            background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1511447333015-45b65e60f6d5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2023&q=80');
          "
        ></div>
        <div
          style="
            background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501529301789-b48c1975542a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80');
          "
        ></div>
        <div
          style="
            background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520263115673-610416f52ab6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80');
          "
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <button class="down-button">
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="up-button">
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Дополните код HTML разметкой

Comment: @Simon изменил)